# Construct a bijection from $\Bbb N$ to $\Bbb N \times [3]$ ??

Tags: combinatorics

Can anyone help with this question? I’m having a lot of trouble understanding how to do this problem. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Do you mean $[3] = \{1,2,3\}$?

Comment: ...or $[3] = \{3\}$?

Comment: I meant [3] as in {1,2,3}

Answer (score 0):

Just divide the natural numbers by their residue modulo $3$, i.e. define the map $f \colon \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N} \times \{0,1,2 \}$ as follows
\begin{equation}
f(n)= \begin{cases}
(n/3,0) \quad \text{if} \ 3|n \\
(\frac{n-1}{3},1) \quad \text{if} \ n=1 \ \text{mod} \ 3 \\
(\frac{n-2}{3},2) \quad \text{if} \ n=2 \ \text{mod} \ 3.
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

The basic idea is that since the cardinality of $\mathbb{N}$ is infinite then $3 \cdot |\mathbb{N}|= |\mathbb{N}|$. More concretely the set $\{ 3n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is in bijection with $\mathbb{N}$ just by the map $n \mapsto 3n$, thus adding $0,1, 2$, i.e. shifting the multiples of $3$ by the possible residues of the division by $3$ we get all the natural numbers.